# Connecting Google colab to a VM instance in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, gcloud, putty

I am running into issues to connect my google colab file to a VM instance in google cloud platform in order to do object detectiont training using tensor flow.

Whenever I try to connect my VM instance too my google colab I get the error message:

[image: Unable to connect to the runtime]

I contacted google in this instance and they told me they don't know what the issue is giving me this response:

> I reviewed the logs of your VM instance again but I didn't see any unusual message or an error related to your VM instance SSH, in the operation logs, stackdriver logs serial logs and activity logs, I also checked the port number 22 on your VM instance and it is opened meaning no firewall rule from VM instance or GCP firewall is blocking the SSH service.
>
> We replicated this on our end but were unable to successfully configure following the documentation (1) you provided on Medium. Please note that the content on Medium is not Google maintained documentation and we cannot vouch for its accuracy and it was posted last year 2019.
>
> Furthermore, please understand that Jupyter is a third-party product not supported by Google Cloud Platform and is outside our scope of expertise. At this point, I am unable to assist you further with this issue and I would recommend that you post a topic of this kind of concern to Stackoverflow (2) for further assistance.

Eventough I followed the guidelines and instructions from their customer support which advised me to follow this guide: https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e. I still get this error message.

(1) https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e

(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory
ref:_00D00VNwG._5005w1fvDwX:ref

Does anyone know how I could possibly solve this issue?

Comment: Your file is in your google drive and you are trying to access the file in the jupyter notebook in your VM instance?

Comment: I have a google colab notebook open, in which I run python code that uses a gpu to do tensorflow training. The files are added too my google colab folder from google drive

Comment: But the problem isn't with the file. I can link the file too my colab withouth issue. The problem is connecting VM's from google cloud platform too my google colab notebook

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It does cover:software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical answerable problem that is unique to software development